# <!-​- language: none --> as an option for language formatting

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Does the explicit language formatting tag have a none option? For a question I'm writing, I'm trying to ASCII out a directory structure, but it keeps getting colored weirdly.

If there is not a `<!-- language: none -->` would other people find this useful?

To be clear, it would still display as a code block, but no syntax coloring would be applied to the code in the block.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two options:

You can pre tag it:

```
foo
bar
```

The above text is:

```
<pre>
foo
bar
</pre>
```

Or you can language hint it for none, though that is `lang-none` (as opposed to `lang-java` and the like).  The full set of language hints can be seen at [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) over on MSE.

```
foo
bar
```

And that bit is:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    foo
    bar
```

Comment: Bookmarking that link! I knew that page was somewhere, but I couldn't find it at all.

Comment: The keyword `none` does work too.

Comment: Hmm, I tried none, and it still coloured numbers, and key words.

Comment: Does `none` work properly in not highlighting C code (the default language)?

Comment: Using `<pre>` tags worked for me. The `<!-- language: lang-none -->` solution didn't work (words appeared still coloured)

Answer (score 7):

## Update: Use three-backticks plus `none`

The [Answer by user289086](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272122/642706) is correct. But since the time that was authored, Stack Exchange has added another formatting code: three backticks (`) on their own line above and below your code. With this approach there is no need to indent your lines of code four spaces.

This new "three-tick" syntax (also known as "code fences", discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks/322000#322000)) on the first line can optionally be followed by the short name of your desired format. For example `java`, or in your case here, `none`.

Here is an example:

````
When run:

```none
INFO - Method `launch` running at 2020-06-28T04:16:17.742443Z
Running Wine report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:20.786653Z
Running Tools report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:30.787891Z
Running Appliance report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:40.791585Z
Running Wine report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:50.796355Z
Running Fruit report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:17:00.800407Z
Running Appliance report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:17:10.805166Z
INFO - Method `shutdown` running at 2020-06-28T04:17:17.783938Z
```

Let's complicate that a bit…
````

That content appears to the reader like this:

> When run:
>
> ```
> INFO - Method `launch` running at 2020-06-28T04:16:17.742443Z
> Running Wine report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:20.786653Z
> Running Tools report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:30.787891Z
> Running Appliance report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:40.791585Z
> Running Wine report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:16:50.796355Z
> Running Fruit report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:17:00.800407Z
> Running Appliance report. Now: 2020-06-28T04:17:10.805166Z
> INFO - Method `shutdown` running at 2020-06-28T04:17:17.783938Z
> ```
>
> Let's complicate that a bit…